# How to render a Tree made of lengthy text nodes in Qt/PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, pyqt4

I'm building an GUI app in which i want to render a tree of lengthy text nodes (something like a typical [hackernews webpage](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23008599)). Since Qt has a rich widget system and there are multiple ways to do the same thing, There is always a question of What is the best way to do it.

To render the tree i'm considering two widgets right now

1. QTreeWidget
2. QtWebEngine

Are there any other widgets/methods in Qt which handle my use case better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTreeWidget` is one option, `QtWebEngine` is extremely heavy and I wouldn't touch it unless you have a clear need to render html content. This stuff can be implemented using a plain `QTextDocument` as the data model, and `QTextEdit` as a view.